# Union and Union all - result

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to understand this result:
Why do I get a result with 100 row in Situation 2.
If I running the code with only 2 first Query I got a result with 18 rows,
So in sotuation 2 I would expect to receive result with 109 rows...?

```
      SELECT FirstName,LastName --9 rows
        FROM employees
       UNION --UNION 1
      SELECT FirstName,LastName  --9 rows
        FROM employees
      UNION ALL --UNION 2
      SELECT companyName, contactName --91 rows
        FROM Customers

--                     UNION 1         UNION 2     RESULT (# Rows)

--Situation 1          UNION          UNION          100
--Situation 2          UNION ALL      UNION          100
--Situation 3          UNION          UNION ALL      100
--Situation 4          UNION ALL      UNION ALL      109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNION statement effectively does a SELECT **DISTINCT** on the results set.

**UNION**

The UNION command is used to select related information from two tables, much like the JOIN command. However, when using the UNION command all selected columns need to be of the same data type. With UNION, only distinct values are selected.

**UNION ALL**

The UNION ALL command is equal to the UNION command, except that UNION ALL selects all values.

The difference between Union and Union all is that Union all will not eliminate duplicate rows, instead, it just pulls all rows from all tables fitting your query specifics and combines them into a table.

**UNION Example:**

```
SELECT 'hello' AS world UNION SELECT 'hello' AS world ;
 world
-------
 hello
(1 row)
```

**UNION ALL example:**

```
SELECT 'hello' AS world UNION ALL SELECT 'hello' AS world ;
 world
-------
 hello
 hello
(2 rows)
```

In your case:

```
--Situation 2          UNION ALL      UNION          100
```

In situation 2, the `UNION`, will remove the duplicates from the first `UNION ALL`

That's the reason you are getting 100 records instead of 109.

```
SELECT 'hello' AS world UNION ALL SELECT 'hello' AS world UNION SELECT 'hello' AS world ;
 world
-------
 hello
(1 row)
```

If you still need all the rows, this is the way

```
SELECT 'hello' AS world UNION ALL (SELECT 'hello' AS world UNION SELECT 'hello1' AS world) ;
 world
--------
 hello
 hello
 hello1
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think most of the answers here are missing the point

---

### The obvious

**UNION** : Combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
  columns
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

**UNION ALL** : The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL

---

### The not obvious

In your case you are UNIONing several queries, with both UNION and UNION ALL.

When the RDBMS engine encounter such case, it applies **precedence** : The last one coming in the query will be applied last.

- if UNION comes after UNION ALL, UNION will be applied last
- if UNION ALL comes after UNION, UNION ALL will be applied last

Example 1

```
select 1
UNION ALL 
select 1
UNION 
select 1
```

Returns one row:

```
1
```

Example 2

```
select 1
UNION
select 1
UNION ALL
select 1
```

Returns 2 rows:

```
1
1
```

---

**The exception to this precedence rule is if you embed 2 UNION queries  with parenthesis, in such case the embed contain will be applied first :**

Lets modify our previous Example 1 :

```
select 1
UNION ALL 
( select 1
  UNION 
  select 1
)
```

Returns 2 rows:

```
1
1
```

---

Reference : [Set Operators - UNION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

To receive 109 result it mean to do UNION ALL to all sub queries 
in your case it mean:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName --9 rows
FROM   employees

UNION **ALL** --UNION 1 *this is the change*

SELECT FirstName,LastName  --9 rows
FROM employees

UNION ALL --UNION 2

SELECT companyName, contactName --91 rows
FROM Customers
```

Comment: Thank! I understand. 
But it's mean that all of the time when I want use with UNION ALL between 2 or many tables (and i have more than tables) i'll need to use UNION ALL in all query?

Comment: yes indeed. 
union all is not the default behavior because usually, you don't want duplicates in your set.